# 12 Hours format in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have function that receive user name and return time in , time out and username in one column.

I used substring to make it into 3 columns and time out return as 24 hours format and I need it into 12 hours format.

```
select substr( FUN1('username'),1,5) TIMEIN , 
       substr( FUN1('username'),7,6) TIMEOUT,
       substr( FUN1('username'),12,100) NAME from dual;
```

Comment: would be useful to see the FUN1 function

Comment: check this link to print in 24hr or 12 hr format: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14987473/convert-24-hour-time-to-12-hour-plus-am-pm-indication-oracle-sql

Comment: I don't have access to this function It is in other db.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `TO_CHAR` function

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(substr( FUN1('username'),1,5), 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') TIMEIN, 
       TO_CHAR(substr( FUN1('username'),7,6), 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') TIMEOUT,
       substr( FUN1('username'),12,100) NAME 
FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by converting the TIMEOUT to a date using TO_DATE assuming the time is in 24 hours format, and then re-converting it to a string using TO_CHAR with the format as 12 hours format -

```
select to_char(to_date('13:00', 'HH24:MI'),'HH:MI AM') from dual;
```

Here's how  your SQL in the question would look like for the TIMEOUT -

```
select substr( FUN1('username'),1,5) TIMEIN , 
   to_char(to_date(substr( FUN1('username'),7,6), 'HH24:MI'),'HH:MI AM') TIMEOUT,
   substr( FUN1('username'),12,100) NAME from dual;
```