# How to order a VARCHAR2 column representing date and time with AM and PM Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

Hello I have the following column and I want to order it by date from earliest to latest. the format looks like this.

```
08/16/2019 08:09:51 AM
```

I came up with this but its giving me an error.

```
ORDER BY date_format(STR_TO_DATE(`END_TIME`,'%m-%d-%y %h:%i:%s %p'),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
```

I couldn't strictly order it by date because 2 PM came before 8 AM which is wrong so I tried to put it in the correct format, I feel like im close. Any ideas?

Comment: cast it as date should work I guess
`order by cast(end_time as date)`

Comment: this looks like mysql, not oracle.  Please update the tag.

Comment: If `end_time` is a `date`, 2 pm would come after 8 am.  Is `end_time` really a string representing a date?  Are `str_to_date` and `date_format` functions that you've created?

Comment: @OldProgrammer its oracle but I got my answer from a similar overflow question guessing this wont work for oracle then.

Comment: @JustinCave it is varchar2 (30 byte) data type!

Comment: Correct.  Is the date stored as as VARCHAR2 type (bad), or an oracle DATE?  If DATE type, you just order by END_TIME

Comment: @OldProgrammer it actually is varchar2 is there a work around? or just remake the table?

Comment: look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14987473/convert-24-hour-time-to-12-hour-plus-am-pm-indication-oracle-sql

Comment: If you are in the design phase of your project, I would refactor to use an actual `DATE` based type for a date value, rather than `VARCHAR2`.

Comment: Are you confused about Oracle company, which is also owner of MySQL DB, with Oracle DB  ?This syntax doesn't belong to Oracle DB.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Op commented here that he has find this solution for mysql that he tried but it is Oracle that he uses...

Comment: Interesting ... I re-looked at the question and the comments and didn't encounter such a comment @VBoka

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan 4th from the top...Sorry, he did not mention that it is mysql but he reply's to the OldProgrammer who asked him that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I am wrong but i do not see nothing wrong here:

```
select to_char(to_date(Date_c,'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM'),'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM') 
from myTable
order by to_date(Date_c,'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM');
```

That is whit this:

```
select *
from myTable
order by to_date(Date_c,'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM');
```

Here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b38dc45d6396eb1ef2713b2ce3b56159)

Comment: This is the correct answer. Thank you so much :) my format was wrong i had AM before but I thought it wouldnt pick up the PM.