# how to get dateTime with AM from oracle using java spring boot

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot

this is my code:

```
List<ReqBody> records = soaDB.query(
                " SELECT TSTMP FROM .... A\r\n"
                        new RowMapper<ReqBody>() {
                            @Override
                            public ReqBody mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {   
                                log.info("ddddddddddddd: {}", rs.getString("TSTMP"));
                                DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH);
                                LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(rs.getString("TSTMP"), formatter);
                                
                                
                                log.info("dateStr: {}", dateTime);

                                ReqBody e = ReqBody.builder()
                                        
                                        .Tstmp(dateTime)

                                        .build();

                                log.info("eeeeeeeeeeeeee {}",e);

                                return e;
                            }

                        });
```

I want to get the full format from the db which is: 26-DEC-23 10.00.00.000000 AM, but I am getting only the date and the hour with out AM (2023-12-26 10:00:00)
why?
is there is a way to get the full format?

Comment: Format it in oracle

Comment: how can I do it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14987473/convert-24-hour-time-to-12-hour-plus-am-pm-indication-oracle-sql

Comment: You don't use the formatter on the end result (`LocalDateTime dateTime`) by the looks, so you will get its default format

Comment: I tried to format it in oracle' but now I get this error:

org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [ SELECT  TO_CHAR (A.TSTMP,

'DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS AM') as TSTMP FROM ....]; SQL state [99999]; error code [17132]; Invalid conversion requested; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid conversion requested

Comment: I see no reason to format this in Oracle - it just makes the code less portable. Get the value using the code in the answer below (use `getObject`) and then *apply the formatter you created*

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, a `TIMESTAMP` is a binary data-type that is composed of 7-13 bytes representing century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute, second and 0-6 bytes for fractional seconds (depending on precision). It **ALWAYS** has those components and it is **NEVER** stored with any particular human-readable format.

> I want to get the full format from the db which is: `26-DEC-23 10.00.00.000000 AM`

No, it is not **stored** in that format; as previously mentioned, the format stored in the database is binary and does not have a human-readable format.

If you want to see the byte values stored in the database then you can use:

```sql
SELECT DUMP(timestamp_column) FROM table_name;
```

> But when I `SELECT` the column via my client application (i.e. SQL*Plus, SQL Developer, etc.) I see the data in the format `26-DEC-23 10.00.00.000000 AM`

That is nothing to do with the database, the database will send the client application you are using the raw binary values; it is the client application that decides how to **display** the date-time values in a meaningful way to you, the user.

For SQL*Plus (and SQL Developer and SQLCl) the [default date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50163432/oracles-default-date-format/50164234#50164234) depends on what country your database thinks it is in (i.e. the `NLS_TERRITORY` setting for the database or your session).

You can see the default format using:

```sql
SELECT value
FROM   NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS
WHERE  PARAMETER = 'NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT';
```

Which, in your case, outputs:

| VALUE |
| --- |
| DD-MON-RR HH12.MI.SS.FF6 AM |

In other client applications you will need to check the documentation for that particular client as to how the default date-time format is set.

---

> I am getting only the date and the hour with out AM (`2023-12-26 10:00:00`) why?

In Java, you are using `rs.getString("TSTMP")` to get the `TIMESTAMP` value so the client application is taking the binary value and implicitly converting it to a string in the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS` (using equivalent Oracle format models).

If you want to parse the value as a string then don't send a `TIMESTAMP` and allow Java to implicitly convert to a string; instead send a formatted string from Oracle:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         TSTMP,
         'DD-MON-RR HH12.MI.SS.FF6 AM',
         'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English'
       ) AS tstmp
FROM   table_name
```

However, in Java, what you probably want to do is to use your current query and pass the value as a `TIMESTAMP` (and not as a string) and then [read the value as a `LocalDateTime`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54907501/1509264) (and not as a string):

```java
LocalDateTime dateTime = rs.getObject("TSTMP", LocalDateTime.class);
```

Then you can format it however you want in Java.